# my swift - Realm app crashes with incompatible library version issue

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am following the To-Do List tutorial on the Realm webpage (https://realm.io/docs/tutorials/realmtasks/) and I am getting the error message when the app crashes:
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Christian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RealmTasks-cwgtsxxmwhutfobpmwhqvankjefr/Build/Products/Debug/RealmTasks.app/Contents/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/Versions/A/RealmSwift
  Reason: Incompatible library version: RealmSwift requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libswiftCore.dylib provides version 0.0.0
(lldb)

[image: screenshot]

There are a number of questions already commented on pointing out that you have to use matching versions for Swift and Realm. I am using Xcode 8.3.2, Swift 3.0.2 and I am using the 3.0.2 versions for Realm and RealmSwift frameworks from the latest download from the realm-mobile-platform directories (6th April 2017).

Might there be something else I am missing here?

Comment: Is the Realm SDK version swift-2.6.2? And did it download from : https://static.realm.io/downloads/swift/realm-swift-2.6.2.zip ?

Comment: well, I tried both, the 2.6.2 and the one in the realm-mobile-platform download one - both don't work

Comment: Can you please share the complete error message, starting with the "dyld: Library not loaded" portion of it?

Comment: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Christian/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RealmTasks-cwgtsxxmwhutfobpmwhqvankjefr/Build/Products/Debug/RealmTasks.app/Contents/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/Versions/A/RealmSwift
  Reason: Incompatible library version: RealmSwift requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libswiftCore.dylib provides version 0.0.0
(lldb)

Comment: "I am using Xcode 8.3.2, Swift 3.0.2 and I am using the 3.0.2 versions for Realm and RealmSwift frameworks" this doesn't line up. Xcode 8.3.2 comes with a Swift 3.1 compiler, and there are no 3.0.2 versions of Realm Objective-C _or_ Realm Swift. The latest Realm versions are at 2.6.2.

Comment: I am using Xcode 8.3.2, but running Swift 3.0.2 on it because Realm Online Server does not work with Swift 3.1 , or am I wrong? Also, the tutorials were created in 3.0.2, so , if you want to follow the tutorial then you have to go back to 3.0.2

Comment: can somebody tell me which configuration I have to use in order to be able to run the Realm Tutorials, in particular which Xcode version?

Comment: According to REALM this is the configuration required:
 - Apps using Realm can target: iOS 8 or later, macOS 10.9 or later, all versions of tvOS and watchOS.
 - Xcode 8.0 or later required. Realm Swift 2.3.0 was the last version to support Swift 2.x and Xcode 7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did all the suggestions from various people in this question and it still did not work, but then I found the problem - the Framework Search Path in Build settings is actually hard coded and pointing at the wrong directory. Once I changed the directory to Swift 3.1 it actually started working. If you could update your above Answer then I can tick it off

Answer (score 0):

“Clean Build Folder” (Command-Option-Shift-K) can occasionally fix issues like these.

Comment: no, still getting the same message. Added more information and a screenshot in above question

Comment: Could you provide us the reproducible project? If you cannot make public your code, please send it to `help@realm.io`. I believe it's not Realm issue. Something wrong in your project settings.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like our tutorials were slightly out of date, so I just submitted an update in order to make mention of Xcode 8.3 and Swift 3.1. Sorry for the confusion.

To 100% clarify, at the time of this writing, the latest versions of all packages involved are:

- Xcode Version: **8.3.2**
- Required Swift Version: **3.1**
- Latest Realm
  Cocoa Release: **2.6.2**

In order to integrate Realm Swift into the tasks tutorial for Xcode 8.3, you need to use the `swift-3.1` version of the frameworks included in either the latest [Realm Swift](https://static.realm.io/downloads/swift/realm-swift-2.6.2.zip) or [Realm Mobile Platform for macOS](https://static.realm.io/downloads/mobile-platform/latest/realm-mobile-platform.zip) bundle downloads.

When setting up the Xcode project, make sure to drag both `Realm.framework` and `RealmSwift.framework` to the 'Embedded Binaries' section of the Xcode project, and ensure 'Copy Items if Needed' is checked to make sure the framework files are properly copied into the project host directory.

Comment: I did all the above and it still did not work, but then I found the problem - the Framework Search Path in Build settings is actually hard coded and pointing at the wrong directory. Once I changed the directory to Swift 3.1 it actually started working. 
If you could update your above Answer then I can tick it off.